# How to only show the MasterView on portrait for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like for iPad that on portrait orientation shows only the MasterView of `UISplitViewController`, and on landscape show the both master view and detail view?
How should I do?

the system is iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience, Use `UIViewController` instead of using `UISpiltViewController` .
In this `UIViewController` have two `UIView` (1-`UITableView` and, 2-`DeatilView` subclass of `UIView`). Now have segue to `DetailView` from cell of `UITableView` . In UIViewController you can have TableView and DetailsView to display like SpiltView.
For `LandScape` and `Portrait` Resize the TableView.
Means Now you can customise according to `orientation`.